# Is there a pseudo inverse $X$ such that $ABX=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

### Question

The title pretty much sums it up. I need to find a matrix $X$ such that:

$A B X = A$,

with $A\in R^{n\times n}$, $\text{rank}(A)=n$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ given. The matrix $X$ should thus “cancel” the non-square $B$.

Does such a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ exist?

---

#### NB:

I am aware of the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse, but this only finds $B$ such that:

$ABA = A$.

Comment: No. What if $B = 0$, for example? The product will then be surely zero also, and thus your claim fails if $A \neq 0$.

Comment: What is the rank of $A$?

Comment: A is of rank $n$, all columns are linearly independent. Assume that $B$ is nonzero, does that make a difference? (It is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rank of $B$ is less than $n$, then $X$ cannot exist, because the rank of $ABX$ is at most equal to the minimum rank of the factors.

Therefore …

> we can assume that $\operatorname{rk}B=n$ and also $n\le m$, that is, $B$ has a right inverse $R$: $BR=I$. Thus $ABR=AI=A$ and $R$ is the requested $X$.

Alternatively, $\operatorname{rk}A=n$ means $A$ is invertible, so you equation is equivalent to

> BX=I

Comment: That assumes that one requires the identity for *all* $A$. The question isn't clear on that, but if you require it only for a specific $A$, you can relax the requirement on $B$ if $A$ doesn't have full rank.

Comment: @fgp In the question it is stated that $A$ has rank $n$.

Comment: @ereg Oh, true.

Comment: @fgp Of course, a generalization for $A$ having any rank would be possible.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. Unfortunately for me the rank of $B$ is less than $n$, so I will need to write problem differently.

Comment: @Ingo If the rank of $B$ is less than $n$, then also $A$ cannot have full rank.